# UK train with declassified first class coach due to overcrowding - any recourse for 1st class ticket holders?

Tags: uk, trains, tickets

Apparently it's half term this week, so the train I took into London today which is normally very full was absolutely heaving. (Why GWR decide to put a 5 coach train on for the first off-peak service of the day, rather than an 8, is a different question....). Due to quite how overcrowded it was, the train staff made an announcement after the second stop saying that the first class coach was being declassified, and standard class passengers currently standing could use it.

While that's good for most of the passengers on the train, I imagine some of the first class ticket holders might be a bit miffed, and any joining later on discovering no seats spare very miffed!

That leads me to wonder - when the first class section on a UK train is declassified by the train manager like that, are first class ticket holders entitled to any kind of compensation / partial refund? And does it depend if they now can't get a seat or not?

Comment: tbh why isn't there a refund when there are no seats for standard tickets either?

Comment: @JamesRyan In France and Belgium, there are 2nd class tickets with and without seat reservation. The former option is more pricy, but there's a seat number printed on your ticket, which allows you to claim your place even if you join the train midway.

Comment: @JamesRyan In the UK at least, a standard class ticket gets you the right to travel, that's it, no right to a seat. There are some commuter services running [at over twice as many people as there are seats](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-34195309)

Comment: @Gagravarr I'm well aware of that but its not really good enough and its only the case now because historically there were mostly enough seats. Since standing and seating are a vastly different experience they should already be charged at different rates even in standard class sections of a train.

Comment: @JamesRyan There's no record of who was standing and who was sitting, so there's really no way to charge at different rates. There's also the complication of people who may have stood for only part of the journey.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I agree it's very annoying, as the main reason to purchase first class is a bit of extra space and some peace and quiet.

Rule G 38 suggests you may be entitled to the fare difference between first and standard class, if one interprets "declassified" as meaning "no longer first class but just another standard class coach".

> G. TRAIN ACCOMMODATION AND RESERVATIONS
>
> 38. **Travelling in standard class accommodation with a first class ticket**
>
>     If you have a first class ticket (or the equivalent) and the
>       first class accommodation (or the  equivalent) shown in the National
>       Rail Timetable is not available in any train you travel in,  you may
>       claim a refund of the difference in price between the first class and
>       the standard  class ticket for the relevant part of your journey.

http://www.nationalrail.co.uk/static/documents/content/NRCOC.pdf

This rule does not apply to season ticket holders.

Virgin Trains also explicitly provides this guarantee, although disingenuously they suggest it is their idea: https://www.virgintrainseastcoast.com/customer-service/seat-guarantee/

Comment: Anecodtaly, I've heard the condutor announce on First Transpennine services where they have allowed all travellers to access first class that first class ticket holders can apply for a refund (of the difference in price)

Comment: @Cmaster Yeah it sounds great, but it's a form to remember to fill out, probably the ticket barrier will swallow your ticket coupon and you will have no evidence you even took a train, you still didn't get the peaceful journey you desired ... and no doubt the difference between first and standard will be computed at the difference between a discount first and a full flexible standard ticket

Comment: Is this going to depend on whether the definition of "first-class" actually includes that it will be half-empty? (Which I assume it doesn't). I doubt that the mere presence of people who only bought a standard class ticket, means that first-class accommodation was not available. If the operator doesn't want to pay won't they just say it was available, but some passengers were given it cheap?

Comment: @SteveJessop Declassifying first class (ie allowing standard-class passengers in) constitutes making it standard-class accomodation. If there are people on an STD ticket, then it's not 1ST any more.

Comment: Ah great, if that's what the conditions of carriage say then they haven't a leg to stand on. I suppose if they wanted to save the money from issuing refunds, then they could have sold upgrades to first class for 1p such that there were no standard passengers in first class. Although this would require the foresight to have a machine on board which can do that...

Comment: @Calchas The refund is for the difference between the ticket you hold and the matching STD ticket, ie Advance First to Standard Advance or First Anytime to Standard Anytime. But the rest of your complaints are entirely reasonable.

Comment: @SteveJessop Upgrades have to be using a ticket that is loaded onto ORCATS, they can't just make up an upgrade as they go along. And if there was a 1p upgrade, they'd have to let you use it on any train.

Comment: Out of interest, by what principle is it that they can't offer cheaper fares which only apply to a particular train and in limited numbers? I won't argue whether it does or should take too long to put this limited special offer onto the system even if it were legally possible: obviously my hare-brained scheme faces multiple obstacles :-)

Comment: If this happened to me I'd get off the train. How horrible.

Comment: @Calchas I imagine here should some way to prove you took the trip. Take people on a business trip who have to file an expenses report: there has to be a way for them to get some sort of proof.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev In my case I retain the credit card receipt or photograph the ticket coupon with my phone, or ultimately send in a redacted copy of my credit card statement, but if you remember you can ask an attendant to let you out by hand instead of using the barrier. But it's still a hassle!

Comment: @SteveJessop They do offer cheap fares that only apply to certain trains and they do apply capacity controls on certain tickets (only "Advance" tickets). If you look at http://www.brfares.com/#!fares?orig=YRK&dest=EDB and scroll down you can see many many different fares that could be sold.

Comment: @RichardGadsden Not every first ticket has a "matching" ticket. But thank you for the clarification, I suppose it's as good as you can expect.

Comment: @JoeBlow And not get to your destination/get to your destination late? You'll still have your seat and services. As a aside, they're pretty reluctant to do this - I've only seen it happen on trains that were dangerously overcrowded - ie in Standard Class people were being crushed. It wouldn't be necessary at all if the seat proportions were more sensible on UK trains, but they so rarely are.

Comment: Seat proportions are badly out in the UK because many more people used to travel first-class (it used to be normal for anyone travelling at company expense), and trains were ordered on that basis. The big increase in fares in the last 10-15 years means that most employers only refund standard-class fares now, so first-class gets emptier. New trains are mostly ordered with different proportions, e.g. ⅔:4⅓ on TransPennine's current order - but the average train is ~20 years old.

Comment: My experience with Thameslink/Southern/Gatwick Express and South West Trains is that season ticket holders **are** entitled to a refund of the First Class portion of the fare for the affected journey. And passengers with tickets which would be retained by the barriers can always retain them if they show them to barrier staff.

Answer (score -4):

A couple of points 
1 - unlike in France and Germany it is FREE to reserve a seat when you buy your ticket. No additional cost. If you do not get a seat you have reserved you can claim a FULL refund. The cost of your ticket therefore DOES INCLUDE A RESERVED SEAT. it's just down to you to actually reserve it
...

2 - The National Conditions of Travel are the MINIMUM standard and what all train operators have to apply. Most train operators go well beyond that and I can't think of anyone who wouldn't refund the difference in cost for first class passengers travelling in a declassified coach.

3 - yes it's a form you need to fill put but how else would you do it? it's like saying you want to return a dress and getting arsey because they want you to take it back to the shop.

Comment: Re point 1, many of the services that are most subject to overcrowding, ie the commuter routes, do not offer seat reservations, so what you write is a bit disingenuous.